# Spy on function called from a React Functional Component

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a React Functional Component, and I want to write a unit test that checks if a function that gets called further down the chain has actually been called as a result of the component getting rendered.

I don't care which library I use, or which exact method from said library I use - I just want to be able to test that `otherHelper` has been called, so feel free to suggest other approaches than this one below.

**helper.ts**

```
export const otherHelper = () => {}

export const helper = () => {
  otherHelper()
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { helper } from './helper'

const App = () => {
  helper()

  return <h1>App</h1>
}
```

Now, here is what I'd like my test to be:

**App.test.tsx**

```
import { App } from './App'
import {otherHelper} from './helper'
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'

describe("App", () => {
  it("calls otherHelper", () => {
    const RenderedApp = render(<App />)
    const spy = jest.spyOn(RenderedApp, otherHelper)
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()    
  })
})
```

Currently this does not work. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Because Jest's `spyOn` method requires an object, I'd be happy to re-write my otherHelper code as follows:

**helper.ts**

```
export const otherHelper = { 
  help: () => {} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the entire `helper` module, see jest docs for [mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules).

In your case it might be something like:

```
const mockedHelper = jest.fn(() => true);
jest.mock('./helper', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./helper');
  return {
    helper: mockedHelper,
    ...originalModule
  };
});

...

expect(mockedHelper).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your expect statement just checks if the entire module has been called. How do you check if `otherHelper` has been called?

Comment: instead of returning `helper: mockedHelper` in the mock, try `otherHelper: mockedHelper,`.

Comment: you might need to change your import in the App component from `import { helper } from './helper'` to `import { otherHelper } from './helper'`

Comment: When I do `jest.mock('./helper')`, then I can test it with `.toHaveBeenCalled()`, but when I do it with the factory as above in your example, then it does not work. Same goes for `otherHelper`.

Comment: This solution did not work. :(